# Changing DELL PE2950 Bios settings remotely

Tags: dell, remote, bios

I'm trying to set up remote console redirection on a few Dell boxes and I was wondering if there were anyway to turn that on without rebooting the machine and going into the BIOS. Has anyone ever done anything like this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Dell OMSA tools installed, you can make updates to the BIOS from within the running OS.  I'm more familiar with the Linux CLI version of the tools (look for commands like "omreport" and "omconfig"), but you should be able to make similar changes on Windows systems as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have to reboot.  Setting up the console redirection requires, at minimum, a kernel command line option, and maybe BIOS tweaks.

Does the server have a DRAC?  If so, there is an article [here](http://deletionpedia.dbatley.com/w/index.php?title=Dell_DRAC_Remote_SSH_Console_Redirection_%28deleted_01_Aug_2008_at_07:34%29) about how to set it up.

Comment: Yeah, I have the kernel stuff all set up, just not the BIOS. It does have a drac, thanks for the link, that looks promising.